# R Repeat for loop is meeting break condition, but not breaking

Tags: r, loops, break

I have a list of 29 matrices called "M", and if a matrix has less than 227 rows I want to keep adding NA rows until it has 227 rows.

I have code that produces exactly what I want, however, I need to stop R manually since the break isn't working.

```
library(tibble)

repeat{
  for(i in 1:29){
    if(dim(M[[i]])[1] < 227){       # if a matrix has less than 227 rows, I want to add a row
      M[[i]] <- M[[i]] %>% add_row
      if(dim(M[[29]])[1] == 227){     # if the final matrix has 227 rows, I want it to break
        break
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have checked the break condition after, and it is true.

```
identical(dim(M[[29]])[1], 227)
[1] TRUE
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to dynamically get the number of rows with `sapply`, take the `max` ('mx').  Use that to check each of the elements of 'M', `if` it is lower than 'mx', then assign new rows as `NA` and return the matrix

```
mx <- max(sapply(M, nrow))
M1 <- lapply(M, function(x) {
           if(nrow(x) < mx) {
             x[(nrow(x) + 1):mx,] <- NA
            }
            x})
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a great alternative, thanks for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

You break the inner loop `for (i in 1:29)`.  You never break the outer `repeat` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, do you know of a quick way to change my above code so that it breaks the repeat loop?

Comment: Actually, this was answered in another answer, thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Break the loop just before the end of the outer `repeat` loop. Then the code works.

First, I will make up a data set.
It will try to create matrices with at most `max_rows` rows.

```
library(magrittr)
library(tibble)

df <- tibble(x = 1:3, y = 3:1)
M <- list(df, df, df)
max_rows <- 8
n <- length(M)

repeat{
  for(i in seq_along(M)){
    if(nrow(M[[i]]) < max_rows){       # if a matrix has less than 227 rows, I want to add a row
      M[[i]] <- M[[i]] %>% add_row
    }
  }
  if(nrow(M[[n]]) == max_rows){     # if the final matrix has 227 rows, I want it to break
    break
  }
}

nrow(M[[n]])
#[1] 8
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you for this! Looking at your code now, I was able to just move the brackets as you did and it works great. I think I understand now what was going on with break, it's now pointing to the repeat.